# Summoners Rift chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat

I recently saw that there is a currently frozen room on this site mainly made for League of Legends discussions and I'm asking myself whether or not it would be possible (and a good idea) of reopening the chatroom.

Was there any particular reason why it was frozen or was it just a matter of inactivity for a rather long time. I feel like LoL questions are becoming more frequent again with the end of season four and maybe reviving the old chatromm could be helpful for slightly off-topic discussions about the tournaments and quick help with minor problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rooms are automatically frozen after a certain period of inactivity. The [Summoner's Rift](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2348/summoners-rift) chat room was active for a while, but activity naturally fell off for a variety of reasons. I unfroze the room just now. If it takes off again, great! If it doesn't, it'll get frozen again automatically.